# how to upload file to ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, server

I am not used to ubuntu as I used windows 7 before. I got a project and need to upload to the server. but it seems it is and ubuntu server.

I have these information:

the server: 54.218.62.191

login key:

user:

how can I upload my files which are html, js and php ?

and I also I need to create database needed for user signup page.

any help will be highly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Do you know the protocol you're supposed to use? (FTP, SSH, etc.)

Comment: I used ftp on windows .

Comment: "It depends": you could use ssh (scp, sftp), ftp, http, smb, nfs, webdav or any number of protocols. It all depends on how the administrator has configured things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to upload to ubuntu using the ssh proctol from Windows, you can use the free software [winscp](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php)

And this gives a proper howto in case you are using winscp to connect to AWS server:  https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_ec2